# indicator-multiload messed up after upgrade to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, xubuntu, indicator, indicator-multiload

I recently upgraded from Xubuntu 14.04 to Xubuntu 16.04, and the system load indicator (indicator-multiload) isn't displaying correctly. It looks like this:

[image]

This is how I want it to look, with a graph for each monitor (CPU, memory, network, etc) and without the label:

[image]

I clicked on it → *Preferences* and tried resetting the settings to the default (*Advanced* → *Revert*, *Menu items* → *Revert*, etc), but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Edit:** I haven't personally seen this bug in Ubuntu 18.04 so it may only apply to older versions of Ubuntu.

This appears to be due to a bug: [indicator-multiload display keeps resetting on its own](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-multiload/+bug/1740751). If you're having the same issue, please go to that link, log in, and click *Does this bug affect you?* near the top left so it gets more visibility.

The workaround is simple enough, although unfortunately it's only temporary; for whatever reason the value keeps getting changed on its own:

```
dconf reset /de/mh21/indicator-multiload/general/indicator-expression-index
```

If that doesn't do the trick, you can also reset all of the indicator-multiload settings to default:

```
dconf reset -f /de/mh21/indicator-multiload/
```

If you do that, you'll have to redo your customizations by clicking on the indicator → *Preferences*